# Concatenate multiple tables values with auto increment when inserting to another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, select, sql-insert, window-functions

I have 2 tables in MySQL that looks like this:

[image]

Note that category_id is FOREIGN KEY of category_key in categories table

I would like to INSERT to a third table (named "catalog") catalog items, such that every catalog ID will be generated from it's category and sub-category ID with auto increment number for each of concatenation of category-sub-category ids.

For Example:

Suppose we have a row in "categories" table which the category_key is "ABC", and we also have a row in "sub_categories" table which the sub_category_key is "EFG", so one row in the catalog table will have the key "ABC-EFG-0001", the other on the same sub-category will have "ABC-EFG-0002", and so on.

And for other ID values, for example. category_id="OMG" and sub_category_id="YYY", the increment of the number will start from 1, so the ID will be "OMG-YYY-0001".

Can I have an example for an INSERT query to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the relation between `categories` and `sub_categories`, ie to which column in `categories` relates foreign key `sub_categoriers(category_id)`?

Comment: @GMB Yes, thanks, the post is edited with this clarification

Comment: OK so both columns should have the same datatype: `sub_categories(category_id)` should be a  `string` column too (and actually it would be better named `category_key`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` (available in MySQL 8.0) to assign the numbers and `LPAD()` to format them. Note that you don't need to use table `categories`, since all relevant information is available in `sub_categories` (but if you do need it, you just have to add a `JOIN`).

```
INSERT INTO catalog
SELECT 
    sc.*,
    CONCAT(
        category_key,
        '-',
        sub_category_key,
        '-',
        LPAD(
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_key, sub_category_key ORDER BY sub_category_key),
            4,
            0
        ) 
    )
FROM sub_categories sc
```